# How to start culebratester2 server on more than one device?

Tags: android, androidviewclient

I want to start culebratester2 server on multiple devices at the same time in order to use `uiautomatorhelper` with `AndroidViewClient` in Python to test the same app on many devices. I don't know if it possible because I'm not able to specify a different forward port using the command `./culebratester2 start-server` and using `AndroidViewClient`. Is there a way to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You were absolutely right, there was no way of specifying the local and remote ports... until now.

Get the latest [CulebraTester2-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public) or run it directly using `curl` as explained in [How to run CulebraTester2 ?](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public#how-to-run-culebratester2-) and you have these new options:

```
./culebratester2 --help
usage: culebratester2 [-h|--help] [-n|-dryrun] {forward-port | run-instrumentation | start-server | install | uninstall }

positional arguments:
 forward-port          uses adb to forward port 9987
     [--local-port PORT] [--remote-port PORT]
 install               installs on device
 run-instrumentation   runs the instrumentation and starts the server
 start-server          starts the server on the device
 uninstall             uninstalls pkgs on device

optional arguments:
 -h, --help            show this help message and exit
 -n, --dryrun          does not execute the commands
```

so you can specify the port either for `forward-port` or `start-server` (which invokes `forward-port` internally).

For example:

```
./culebratester2 start-server --local-port 6543
```

this way you would be able to specify a different local port for each device.

There is also a new command line option `--dryrun` if you want to check what it is going to do before actually doing it.